# The safest way to add integer into array value without having to call it?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv

What is the safest way to add integer into array value without having to call the array value ? In this case I would rather not to call the array value because the array is inside a nested loop and the loop itself can repeat for thousands times.

For example dots[1] = I want to add value of this array with 3. Here's my sample code :

```
void box(const Mat &dots, Mat &newdots, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dots.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dots.cols; j++) {
            newdots.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = dots.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0]; 
            newdots.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = dots.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1]; //add this with 3
            newdots.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = dots.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2]; //add this with 5
        }
    }
```

Is it possible ? Any suggestion how to do it ? Thanks.

Comment: what is `dots`? you can't "call" normal arrays, they have no `operator ()`.

Comment: It's an example to give the idea that the array value is from (i,j), the original code worked already. Now I need to perform addition. I'm working using OpenCV in c++, and use operator () for my arrays.

Comment: If you are already using `operator ()` with `dots` then it is definitely not an array. At least not normal C++ array. Most likely some container class.

Comment: I posted the original code. Please kindly take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simplest way is to use [`cv::add`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#add), which overloads the `+` operator for the `Mat` class:

```
// Create a Mat of all 0's
cv::Mat dots = cv::Mat(5, 4, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
std::cout << "dots:\n" << dots << std::endl;

// Add 0 to the B channel, 3 to the G channel, and 5 to R
cv::Mat newdots = dots + cv::Scalar(0, 3, 5);
std::cout << "newdots:\n" << newdots << std::endl;
```

Result:

```
dots:
[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]
newdots:
[  0,   3,   5,   0,   3,   5,   0,   3,   5,   0,   3,   5;
   0,   3,   5,   0,   3,   5,   0,   3,   5,   0,   3,   5;
   0,   3,   5,   0,   3,   5,   0,   3,   5,   0,   3,   5;
   0,   3,   5,   0,   3,   5,   0,   3,   5,   0,   3,   5;
   0,   3,   5,   0,   3,   5,   0,   3,   5,   0,   3,   5]
```

Note that `dots += Scalar(0,3,5)` also works if you just want to modify the original `Mat`.